# Getting user gender via spring social for facebook

Tags: spring, facebook, spring-social

We have developed an app that let user login with facebook. The app has been granted all required permissions to retrieve name, email, gender and age range etc. But our app developer stored only id,name and email while user login. Now we need to retrieve gender and age range of all those users who have logged in the app.

Is there a way to rerun user query to retrieve those data? I am looking to develop an program using Spring-social and RestFB but it needs user login action to retrieve required data which is problem in our case since we cannot recreate login action again.

Comment: If you have a valid access token for that user you can request the data again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the user granted `public_profile` permission to your app, and you have their app-scoped user id, you can make the API call using your app access token.

And if you are looking to request this data for a lot of users, then you should optimize your requests in the following ways:

- request the fields you need only: `/user-id?fields=id,gender`
- request data for multiple users in one go: `/?ids=user-id-1,user-id-2,user-id-3&fields=fields=id,gender` – https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.5#multirequests
- perhaps even use Batch Requests if necessary, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests/